# Mocking assert_called_with in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm having some trouble understanding why the following code does not pass:

***test.py***

```
import mock
import unittest

from foo import Foo


class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('foo.Bar')
    def test_foo_add(self, Bar):
        foo = Foo()
        foo.add(2, 2)
        Bar.add.assert_called_with(2, 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

***foo.py***

```
from bar import Bar

class Foo(object):
    def add(self, x, y):
        bar = Bar()
        return bar.add(x, y)
```

***bar.py***

```
class Bar(object):
    def add(self, x, y):
        print('b.Bar --> Adding {} + {}'.format(x, y))
        return x + y
```

In the code, `Foo.add` creates an instance of `Bar` and returns the result of `Bar.add` when invoked. Why does testing `assert_called_with` for `Bar.add` fail? I believe I am mocking the `Bar` in the correct place (I am mocking `foo.Bar` because that is the namespace which it is being looked up, rather than `bar.Bar`).

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/iain/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 1201, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "test.py", line 12, in test_a_b
    fake_Bar.add.assert_called_with(2, 2)
  File "/Users/iain/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 831, in assert_called_with
    raise AssertionError('Expected call: %s\nNot called' % (expected,))
AssertionError: Expected call: add(2, 2)
Not called

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are mocking the method call in the right place. However, since you are calling the method from an instance, it is a bound method, and thus receives the instance as the first argument (the `self` parameter), in addition to all the other arguments.

**Edit**: Since `Bar` is replaced with a `Mock` instance, `Bar().add` does not know it's a method (and hence is not bound to anything). In other words, `Bar` is a `Mock`, `Bar()` is a `Mock`, and `Bar().add` is also a `Mock`. `bar.add` is thus a newly created mock, called with arguments `(2, 2)`. One way of asserting this call would be:

```
@mock.patch('foo.Bar')
def test_foo_add(self, Bar):
    foo = Foo()
    foo.add(2, 2)
    Bar.return_value.add.assert_called_with(2, 2)
```

Depending on how your actual code looks, you may want to instead mock the method rather than the class:

```
@mock.patch('foo.Bar.add')
def test_foo_add(self, bar_add):
    foo = Foo()
    foo.add(2, 2)
    bar_add.assert_called_with(2, 2)
```

Comment: I've modified the test so that `foo` is passed as the first arg to `Bar.add.assert_called_with()` but still the test fails? The output reads the same (AssertionError: Expected call: add(<foo.Foo object at 0x102108a50>, 2, 2) Not called)

Comment: Whoops, my sample code was totally wrong. Will update in a few with the proper answer. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks! I think I fell made the mistake of thinking that if I mocked `foo.Bar` then all of its attributes and methods remained intact and unchanged unless I explicitly changed their behaviour . Would this be a case where one might use the `mock.patch.object` method instead?

Comment: `patch.object` and `patch` have identical functionality; they simply use a different way of referring to the object to patch. To patch `Bar` in the `foo` module, you would use `mock.patch(foo, 'Bar')`, and the results would be the same. I don't know of a pre-built way of getting the behavior you want, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

I believe your problem would be solved like this:

```
from bar import Bar

class Foo(object):
    def add(self, x, y):
        self.bar = Bar()
        return self.bar.add(x, y)
```